# Question about isosceles trapezium ABCD, AB ∥ DC and AD = BC.

Tags: geometry

Question about isosceles trapezium ABCD, AB ∥ DC and AD = BC. AC and BD intersect at M. ∠AMB = 60. P, Q, R are the midpoints of MA, MD, BC respectively. Prove that ∆PQR is equilateral.

I tried solving using midpoint theorem, but I am getting stuck. Please guide.

[image]

Comment: I have added an image, please check

Comment: Hint. $BPC$ and $BQC$ are right triangles

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek tried but could not get it, could you please post the solution?

Comment: Hint 2. In a right triangle, the midpoint of the side opposite the right angle is the center of the circumscribed circle. So you could get $BR=PR=QR=CR$

Comment: oh ok got it, thank you!

Comment: I don't understand why our curators dislike elementary-school geometry problems. They are very beautiful, challenging for those who are getting to prove things for the first time. It it get closed I will vote to have it reopen. I see no reason to close it!

Answer (score 3):

Connect mid point of AB (E) to that of DC(H).Draw circucircle of triangle PQR, it intersect MB and MC at N and T respectively. We have:

$$\angle AMB=\frac{\overset{\large\frown}{PN}+\overset{\large\frown}{QT}}2=60^o$$

$$\Rightarrow \overset{\large\frown}{PN}+\overset{\large\frown}{QT}=120^o$$

Since trapezoid is symmetric about EH, so we have:

$$\overset{\large\frown}{NT}=\overset{\large\frown}{PQ}=120^o$$

Which gives:

$$\angle PRQ=60^o$$

Now draw diameter RE, it bisects angle PRQ because E is point where DA is tangent to the circumcircle. therefore:

$\overset{\large\frown}{EP}=60^o$

$\Rightarrow \overset{\large\frown}{PR}=120^o $

Which gives:

$$\angle PQR=60^o$$

Hence triangle PQR is equilateral.

Comment: you may want to vote to reopen this question. The Vogons stroke again and closed this question. Next thing they may want to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using complex numbers geometry.

We start from the fact that triangle $MAB$ and, as a consequence $MDC$ are equilateral triangles. We will consider WLOG that their resp. sidelengths are $1$ and $s$.

Let us take $M$ as the origin and the parallel to lines $AB$ and $DC$ passing through $M$ as the $x$ axis (the $y$ axis being the line passing through midpoints of $AB$ and $DC$, resp.)

Let us use complex numbers representation associating the lowercase letters to the uppercase letters attributed to points), with $$w:=b=e^{i \pi/3}.$$

To points $A,D,C,P,Q,R$ resp. we associate:

$$a=w^2, d=sw^4, c=sw^5, p=\tfrac12w^2, q=\tfrac12sw^4, r=\tfrac12(w+sw^5)$$

Triangle $PQR$ is equilateral iff the $\pi/3$ rotation centered in $P$ maps $Q$ to $R$, i.e.,

$$\mathscr{R}_{\pi/3}(\vec{PQ})=\vec{PR} \ \iff \ w(q-p)=r-p$$

This relationship is equivalent to:

$$w(\tfrac12sw^4-\tfrac12w^2)=\tfrac12(w+sw^5)-\tfrac12w^2 \ \iff \  w=1+w^2   $$

which is true.

Comment: Any comment ? ...

Comment: I am not actually allowed to use complex numbers geometry for the solution, but thank you!